# cannot access value of dynamically generating radio button in angularjs controller using scope

Tags: angularjs

I am showing radio button in html using practices is a json array

```
<div id="rows" ng-repeat="practice in practices">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="practice.id" ng-value="practice.id">
</div>
```

When I tried to access value of this radio button using code mentioned below in controller, it gave me a message `"undefined...."`

```
$window.alert($scope.practice.id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you put something in an `ng-repeat` it puts the values in a child scope - so you would need to access the individual values of the `practices` collection by index of the collection.

like so:

```
$scope.practices[index].id
```

the other option is to also have a `ng-click` directive that would allow you to be notified on the user selecting the id - which you could do two ways

either:

```
ng-click="changedPracticeId($index)"
```

this would call the function defined in scope with the index, so you could access the individual item by index, like above. then the function could look something like this:

```
$scope.changedPracticeId = function (index) {
    window.alert($scope.practices[index].id);
}
```

or

```
ng-click="changedPracticeId(practice.id)"
```

this would give you the id of the value so your function would look something like this:

```
$scope.changedPracticeId = function (id) {
    window.alert(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

don't see a controller per input row, so your controller is probably for ALL radio buttons.
so what you got in your scope is actually $scope.practices and not $scope.practice.
if you want to see any change, you can use

```
$scope.$watchCollection('practices', function (newValue) {...});
```